# iOS7: "xx will be different at runtime"

Tags: constraints, ios7

Just installed the iOS7 version XCode5 and trying to get my app perfectly running on iOS7. What does this error mean? I've got over 20 of them for an app with only 3 views. I guess it's the constraints? However I didn't have any errors on iOS6 and the views actually all look well aligned in the simulator and on my iPhone. What am I missing?

BTW: The constraints seem changing whenever I open xcode. After I've built the one view from scratch and restarted XCode later there were some additional constraints added by the system itself. Why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warnings: Misplaced View](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919739/warnings-misplaced-view)