# How to show status bar in storyboard of Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, status

I'm trying to develop an app that has a navigation controller at the top.  When viewing the app on the storyboard as an iPhone 7 Plus, the status bar is visible, and the layout is correct.  When viewing as any other device, the status bar is missing, and the layout is off by 20px. I also get a "misplaced view" warning.

I believe this has to do with the issue working while developing on my work computer, but then when I switch to my laptop, the Misplaced View errors start happening.

When running the app, the app works fine and looks as it should regardless of the device, but with everything off like this, it's hard to develop.

Did I change some default setting on my laptop to not show the status bar on some views in the storyboard view?  Thanks for any help!

[iPhone 7 example showing no status bar in storyboard view, as well as incorrect placement of cells / views / images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aI96F.png)

## EDIT:

Update: [At work (different Mac running Xcode with the same project files, the status bar shows on every preview (meaning no misplaced views).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDVcL.png)    It's got to be something with my Xcode settings at home.  Any ideas?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919739/warnings-misplaced-view

Comment: have you given the constraint properly?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik his main problem is the status bar not the misplaced views

Comment: In the right have the option to show or hide the status bar, you can try that?

Comment: @Tj3n - have tried that :)

Comment: @RockBalbao, yes, however using Xcode of a different Mac works fine (shows status bar in storyboard view for all devices).  At home on my mac, Xcode only shows the status bar for an iPhone 7 Plus.  Got to be an Xcode issue, considering the code is the same.

Comment: I've had this problem for several years, where the status bar settings in `Info.plist` don't seem to take effect. In fact, it just started behaving a documented last month... I don't know where this gets "stuck" in Xcode, but I from reading the confused discussions in stack overflow, I know I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling and reinstalling Xcode on the mac with the issue seemed to solve the problem.  I'm sure it's a bug.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the value of **"Status Bar"** value and its visible into storyboard.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is nit the issue with your VC but is with NavigationController, so select your NavigationVC and check mark the option underTopBars,

[image: NavigationController attribute inspector]

Answer (score 0):

you can do it as

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return false
}
```

Comment: The status bar is showing on one instance of Xcode, but not on another (except for one simulator, the iPhone 7 Plus).   I think it's my Xcode, not the program.  Thank you for the recommendation